# DAX Function Using Variables for Efficiency Purposes

Tags: powerbi, dax

Here is my dax. I keep getting the following error message.

> Keepfilters function can only be used as a top level filter argument
> of calculate and calculate table or with a table argument of a
> function performing a table scan.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Here is my code:

```
GB 1-2 Login Counts =  
var kf_ds_glc_not_empty = KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT]) <> ""
var kf_ds_glc_eq_12 = KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT]) = "1-2"

RETURN

switch(max(GBvsProg[Filter Order]),

    1,
    CALCULATE(COUNT(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT]),
        -- KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT] <> ""), --This is what was here originally.
        kf_ds_glc_not_empty ,
        -- KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT] = "1-2"), --This is what was here originally.
        kf_ds_glc_eq_12,
        KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[PROGRESS_GO_PASSRATECAT] = "Failing 100%") --This is what was here originally.
        ),

    2,
    CALCULATE(COUNT(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT]),
        -- KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT] <> ""), --This is what was here originally.
        kf_ds_glc_not_empty ,
        -- KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT] = "1-2"), --This is what was here originally.
        kf_ds_glc_eq_12,
        KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[PASSING_GO_PASSRATECAT] = "Failing 100%") --This is what was here originally.
        ),

    3,
    CALCULATE(COUNT(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT]),
        -- KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT] <> ""), --This is what was here originally.
        kf_ds_glc_not_empty ,
        -- KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT] = "1-2"), --This is what was here originally.
        kf_ds_glc_eq_12,
        KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[PROGRESS_GO_PASSRATECAT] = "Passing 0-49%") --This is what was here originally.
        ),

    4,
    CALCULATE(COUNT(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT]),
        -- KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT] <> ""), --This is what was here originally.
        kf_ds_glc_not_empty ,
        -- KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT] = "1-2"), --This is what was here originally.
        kf_ds_glc_eq_12,
        KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[PASSING_GO_PASSRATECAT] = "Passing 0-49%") --This is what was here originally.
        ),

    5,
    CALCULATE(COUNT(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT]),
        -- KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT] <> ""), --This is what was here originally.
        kf_ds_glc_not_empty ,
        -- KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT] = "1-2"), --This is what was here originally.
        kf_ds_glc_eq_12,
        KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[PROGRESS_GO_PASSRATECAT] = "Passing 50-74%") --This is what was here originally.
        ),

    6,
    CALCULATE(COUNT(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT]),
        -- KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT] <> ""), --This is what was here originally.
        kf_ds_glc_not_empty ,
        -- KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT] = "1-2"), --This is what was here originally.
        kf_ds_glc_eq_12,
        KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[PASSING_GO_PASSRATECAT] = "Passing 50-99%") --This is what was here originally.
        ),

    7,
    CALCULATE(COUNT(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT]),
        -- KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT] <> ""), --This is what was here originally.
        kf_ds_glc_not_empty ,
        -- KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT] = "1-2"), --This is what was here originally.
        kf_ds_glc_eq_12,
        KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[PROGRESS_GO_PASSRATECAT] = "Passing 100%") --This is what was here originally.
        ),

    8,
    CALCULATE(COUNT(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT]),
        -- KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT] <> ""), --This is what was here originally.
        kf_ds_glc_not_empty ,
        -- KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT] = "1-2"), --This is what was here originally.
        kf_ds_glc_eq_12,
        KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[PASSING_GO_PASSRATECAT] = "Passing 100%") --This is what was here originally.
        )
    ) + 0
```

Comment: It seem like you can only use `keepfilter` once? https://dax.guide/keepfilters/. And it is so scary to look at your dax measure for one calculation, try break it down to easily track if error happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KEEPFILTER can be used only in CALCULATE or CALCULATETABLE function expression or filter.
That mean if you want to use var you should make it this way (using FILTER or CALCULATETABLE in variables):

```
var kf_ds_glc_not_empty = CALCULATETABLE(D_STUDENTS, D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT] <> "" )
```

And in the calculation:

```
   CALCULATE(COUNT(D_STUDENTS[GO_LOGIN_CAT]),
        KEEPFILTERS(kf_ds_glc_not_empty) ,
       KEEPFILTERS( kf_ds_glc_eq_12),
        KEEPFILTERS(D_STUDENTS[PROGRESS_GO_PASSRATECAT] = "Failing 100%") --This is what was here originally.
        ),
```